# How do I select the target framework of a CodeDom compiler using C#?

Tags: c#, codedom

So I have a CodeDOM compiler written in C# that's supposed to compile another application based on one of its resources. How would I change the target .NET framework of the resource (or of the outputted executable of the compiler)?

Comment: That depends on the compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could pass options to the compiler using the [following constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb537926.aspx):

```
var providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
providerOptions.Add("CompilerVersion", "v3.5");
var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You would need to specify it in a dictionary of settings for the compiler, such as:

```
var settings = new Dictionary<string,string>();
settings.Add("CompilerVersion", "v3.5");
var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider(settings);
```

Unsurprisingly, Google already brings up a couple of examples of this, too; [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lukeh/archive/2007/07/11/c-3-0-and-codedom.aspx) and [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/ahoffman/archive/2007/08/29/codedomprovider-targeting-net-3-5.aspx).