# How to force CSharpCodeProvider to compile with a specific target framework

Tags: c#, codedom

I've got a small app, which can compile .cs Scripts using CSharpCodeProvider
It worked fine for years.
Now I've tried a new script and I run into compilation issues.
I tracked it down to the usage of a Func delegate with 5 parameters.
I know, that there was a switch with .NET Framework 4.0, allowing more than 4 parameters.

Yes, I tried to force the usage of a required compiler version:

```
var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } });
```

But it doesn't help. Whenever I add Func parameter #5, the script does not compile, which leads me to the conclusion, it's somehow using the old compiler.

**Any ideas, how to fix this?**

I've searched Stackoverflow for similar problems but haven't found any useful answer.
The usage of Roslyn is not an alternative, since it includes a lot of dependencies, which I would like to avoid in this small script app.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307991/how-to-make-csharpcodeprovider-target-net-4-5-0-instead-of-net-4-6-2?rq=1

Comment: No, this was no help, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example for a problem, which cannot be solved on Friday afternoon, but is easily fixed on Monday morning.

I found out, that my new VisualStudio 2022, when updating the solution, somehow has not taken over the old OutputPath of the app. So I had a new script, but still an old app, which used the v3.5 compiler.

Means, the CompilerVersion setting works as expected.

Sorry for the inconvenience.